# Android ViewPager and Unlimited Views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm working with ViewPager and PagerAdapter to display a Day View calendar.  The calendar will start on today when loaded and the user can then swipe left to get to tomorrow or right to get to yesterday, continuing to swipe in either direction for as far as they want.

The final statement there is the problem.  Is there a way to use ViewPager with an unlimited number of views?

If not is it recommended that I only have 3 ViewPagers and as the user scrolls I remove the previous and add a new one?  I've tested my base code and have been able to set the total number of views to 10,000 and asked the pager to start me on page 5,000 and it works completely fine.

As long as there are no memory concerns, I may just go this route, anticipating that the user will not likely swipe 5,000 days in either direction.

Comment: Looks like I found an upper limit to the number of views you can set.  10,000,000 views seems to cause issues, although the app doesn't crash or get errors at all, just goes back to view 0.  So the highest I can set is 1,000,000 views.  Then I start at view number 500,000.  Clearly this is overkill and setting the limit to 1,000 will be more than enough, starting at view 500.  Let me know if you have a better idea.  -Thanks!  db

Comment: @casperOne Please reopen this question.  My question is in the second paragraph: "Is there a way to use ViewPager with an unlimited number of views?"  This is the question I need help with.  Instead of closing the question, could you please suggest an edit to make the question more applicable to the Q&A format?

Comment: I won't suggest an edit (you, others can do that).  There are two major problems here.  a) "Who else is using it and are you using it with a large amount of views?" is not constructive, nothing can make it constructive or suitable for Stack Exchange.  b) if the question is really "Is there a way to use ViewPager with an unlimited number of views?" then the follow up is "what have you tried" which is the mark of "Not A Real Question"; if I reopened it, I'd just close it as NARQ based on the second point.

Comment: https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for `Fragments` and the accompanying `FragmentPagerAdapter`. For really large data sets (which sounds like your case) than use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

It is available in the v4 compatibility package so you can access it on older versions of the platform.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: Looks like this one still requires you to set a limit on the views up front.  I'd like to have an infinite number of views, in both directions.